# Variables and square number problem

Tags: contest-math, square-numbers

I'm having issues with this problem.

$N + 2000$ is an square number. $N - 17$ is also an square number. Find $N$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let,

$$N+2000=a^2$$

$$N-17=b^2$$

So that,

$$(N+2000)-(N-17)=a^2-b^2$$

$$2017=(a-b)(a+b)$$

$2017$ is prime so there isn't really that many ways to break it apart into multiplication of integers.

Comment: Forgot to add, n must be an positive integer

Comment: Yes I know, this hint should be enough  @HectorMagaña

Comment: Snap, I think I got it, will confirm later since im doing some stuff right now

Comment: $1016081$ is the right answer. $1016064$ is $1008^2$. $1018081$ is $1009^2$

Comment: Note that $1008+1009=2017$ Is it a contest problem ? :D

Answer (score 0):

$N+2000=p^{2}$ (1)

$N-17=q^{2}$ (2)

Substract (2) from (1)

$N+2000-(N-17)=p^{2}-q^{2}$

$2017=(p-q)(p+q)$

2017 is a prime, thus:

$p-q=1$

$p+q=2017$

Solving the system of equations gives you p=1009, q=1008.
Now use p in (1), or q in (2)
$N+2000=1009^{2}$
And the desired number is 1016081.